# How to make functions stop in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to scrape the web using Google Sheets for information that doesn't change often. I wanted to be able to this for many inputs, so I automated the scraping. For example, `=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/",B16), "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/h1/span[2]")`
(outputs company name from given symbol). However, when use this in my sheet, for some reason it will sometimes call again and load again. This would be fine if I didn't have a large data set, but I do. So the result is about a third of my outputs are always loading. I would like them to only reload when I tell them to. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Altought there's not built-in functionality in Google Sheets for what you're describing, you could make a workaround by leveraging *time driven triggers* in Google Apps Script.

A possible approach to solving this porblem would be to make a function that only once in a given time interval (*i.e.* once a day) "updates" the spreadsheet by pasting the formula and then copying and pasting the values. Say , for example, that your formula is in the A1 cell. The code should look like this:

```
function refreshSheet() {

  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("YOUR_SHEETs_NAME"); // You should replace this

  // Formula constant
  let FORMULA =`IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/",B16), "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/h1/span[2]")`;

  let formulaCell = sheet.getRange("A1"); // You should replace this
  formulaCell.setValue(FORMULA); // Pasting the formula

  Utilities.sleep(600); // Wait an apropiate amount of time for the formula to resolve
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  let maxRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  maxRange.copyTo(maxRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); // copy and paste values to the data range

}
```

You can add scripts to Sheets buy going to **Extensions > Apps Script**

Then you should create a `Trigger` by going to **Triggers > Add Trigger**, and add the time and periodicity that you want.